# R: How to set member variable within method?

Tags: r, oop

I'm attempting to store a member variable within a method of an R list.

Example:

```
myclient <- list()

myclient$Login <- function(userName, password) {
    # contact the server and get a token; in this example, just set a value to the token:
    token <- 5
    #... then, store the just received token in a member variable
    myclient$token <- token
    cat(myclient$token)
}

myclient$Login('user', '12345')
cat(myclient$token)
```

prints:

```
5
NULL
```

That is: the member variable (myclient$token) is destroyed when exiting the function (Login).

Is there a way to store it somehow, so that:

1) it could be reused

2) the user (caller of login function) remains agnostic of the member variables (myclient$token)

?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the double arrow (<<-) operator to store member variables globally:

```
myclient <- list()

myclient$Login <- function(userName, password) {
    # contact the server and get a token; in this example, just set a value to the token:
    token <- 5
    #... then, store the just received token in a member variable
    # Notice the double arrow, here!
    myclient$token <<- token
    cat(myclient$token)
}

myclient$Login('user', '12345')
cat(myclient$token)
```

prints:

```
5
5
```